# Link data with user php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So guys I am a newbie to php
I created a signup and login form using php and mysql , and now I have loggedin with a created account.
Now I need to enter data, and I created another table for the data to be entered. But how to enter data (the php code)such that the data is linked to my account, for example lets say I have to enter the number of candies sold, I created a form where it asks "candies sold" with an blank box to enter the number, but how to link that to my user in the database

Any links of youtube or any tutorial would be helpful

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add a short, concise, reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. Lets say I created a website xyz.com with a signup and login. Now I have logged in, and it has a form to fill(the back end has not done yet for that form). The form's purpose is to fetch whatever I write and link it with my user id in the back end, what is the code for that?
( I searched in google , but couldnt get anything , sorry if this question is already asked but for me I didnt find anything)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable with you users login id and link that id to the relevant table in your database along with whatever else is stored in that table of the  database.

```
$id = yourid;
$formdata1 = "foo";
$formdata2 = "baa";
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table(id, data1, data2) VALUES ($id, $formdata1, $formdata1)';
```

Answer (score 0):

When logging in, your user-account probably contains an ID or email to identify the user. Store that information in a session-variable. It will survive between requests, as long as your script in the beginning contains

```
session_start();
```

Each request to the database that should take logged in user into account, should use that information to filter the database-requests.

You will probably gain some speed if you read about PDO and buy a good PHP-book.

Comment: thanks for the help, another problem arised, when i login first (say i login as 'xyz' ) it is stored as xyz, but then when i logout and say I login as 'abc' , it is not stored as abc but as 'Array', how to overcome this

Comment: It is probably due to code changes you've made after logging in as xyz.